# Autopilot vSphere node creation problem

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I followed [this guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-autopilot-testdrive) to try Autopilot on vSphere environment.

I ran `autopilot-config` and everything seems work fine, but no nodes (instead of 3) are displayed inside the MAAS page.

In the maas.log file I see:

```
[ERROR]: Unable to create node on region: Region does not support the Createnode RPC method
```

Can you help me?